# Multiline Textbox Suggestion/Append property

Tags: c#

I am currently in need of a multi-line textbox that can do suggest/append of the desired list items so far I am able to get the suggestion but the only problem is now is that it is working abnormally, i.e. showing suggestion for white spaces, when I press enter in order to autocomplete it gives me multiple strings of that characters, also there is a problem that due to my logic it only show suggestion to the strings that are at the end of the textbox, not the one that is inserted in between.
So far my code is following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace multiline_text_suggest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Controls.Add(listBox);
            listBox.Hide();
            textsplit();
        }
        string intellisenes;
        private void textsplit() {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string c in textBox.Text.Split()) {   
                listBox1.Items.Add(c);
            }

            intellisenes = listBox1.Items[listBox1.Items.Count-1].ToString().Trim();
        }

        void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == (decimal)Keys.Enter)
            {
                textBox.Text += ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString();
                textBox.Focus();
                listBox.Hide();

            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            textsplit();
            listBox.SetBounds(textBox.Left, textBox.Top + textBox.Height, textBox.Width + 20, 40);
            listBox.KeyDown += listBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            List<string> list = new List<string>(){"king","kong"};
            var localList = list.Where(z => z.StartsWith(intellisenes.Trim())).ToList();   
            if (localList.Any() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                listBox.DataSource = localList;
                listBox.Show();
                listBox.Focus();
            }

        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textsplit();
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me for any mistakes since I am just a noob in coding.

Comment: There are two `Listbox`? `listBox` & `listBox1`?

Comment: the listbox is for the suggestion item while the listbox1 is for the spliting the text box strings in order to get the last written string.